# Google web font is not rendering on chrome when i go back?

Tags: html, css

I'm using google chrome and their google web font renders fine on the initial load of a page but when I click on a link and then use my "Back" button, the web font does not render.

I'm on version - Version 48.0.2564.109 (64-bit)

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900,400italic,700italic,900italic%7CArchivo+Narrow:400,400italic,700,700italic%7COswald:400,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Is the CSS loading fine during each attempt?

Comment: I too am on 48.0.2564.109 (64-bit), but this demo works just fine for me: http://output.jsbin.com/nemuqixisu

Answer (score 0):

Try to import it in your css [as that](http://output.jsbin.com/nemuqixisu) and try again

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster);
 h1 {
  font-family: Lobster;
}
```